# How to add month and year dropdown to calendar month view

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I want to add a month and a year dropdown to the month view of calendar so a user can jump to any month from the dropdown and can jump to the year, if selected. (Users can pick month OR year and will get results). I can add an exposed filter that doesn't update the calendar display when I click apply.

Any suggestions of what terms to search for or how to start this. I cannot seem to find tutorials or posts on this other than people saying yeah, I want that but I have no idea how to do it without building a custom calendar or using jquery datepicker.

Comment: So is your question is how to add an exposed date filter that automatically jumps to its selection?

Comment: Yes. I added an exposed filter, but it had no effect on the calendar display. I could select month and year and click apply, but the calendar display doesn't update. It also forces the user to select both month and year, instead of either one. So I must be approaching this wrong, but I need some pointers towards another way to do this. I have searched, but I cannot find anything that seems like it should work, but maybe I am using the wrong terms.

Answer (score 1):

The [Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) has a subproject called **Date Views**. Once that 
module is enabled, you can add exposed filters to your date fields. Setting the filter option **Date selection form element** to *select* will provide the dropdown selection widget for your date.

Finally, under the Advanced > Exposed form > Exposed form style > Settings link there's an **Autosubmit** option that will submit the filter form upon date change.

Comment: This doesn't jump to that month. It simply filters the calendar to only show events with a date in the selected month.